# Filter rows based on values of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I want to extract the rows with at least one value in the columns c1-c10. 
I have data like this (for my data there are in total 11 columns counting the date and Q. Date and Q have values in all rows).

```
 date c1   c2   c3   c4 ...  Q
 1   0.1  NA   NA   NA     300
 2   NA   0.2  1.3  NA     100
 3   NA   NA   NA   NA     200
 4   NA   0.3  NA   0.4    100
 5   NA   1.4  NA   NA     150
 6   NA   NA   NA   NA     200
 7   0.5  0.3   0.5   0.6  100
```

I want to get this

```
 date c1   c2   c3   c4 ...  Q
 1   0.1  NA   NA   NA     300
 2   NA   0.2  1.3  NA     100
 4   NA   0.3  NA   0.4    100
 5   NA   1.4  NA   NA     150
 7   0.5  0.3   0.5   0.6  100
```

I tried this

```
 datawide2<- datawide1 %>% filter(rowSums(.[2:10]!="NULL")>=1)
```

But the result is just the rows that has all values in all columns c1-10.
So in this case just shows me

```
 date c1   c2   c3   c4 ...  Q
 7   0.5  0.3   0.5   0.6  100
```

Can you help me? I don't know what is missing in what I did.

I searched in other questions but didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @David Arenburg, you are misunderstanding `NA` and "NULL". You have `NA`s in your dataframe and you are checking for "NULL". Your code would work if you do

```
#Again taking from David in comments
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(rowSums(!is.na(.[2:5])) > 0)
```

---

This is also a good case to use `filter_at`

```
df %>%
  filter_at(vars(c1:c4), any_vars(!is.na(.)))

#  date  c1  c2  c3  c4   Q
#1    1 0.1  NA  NA  NA 300
#2    2  NA 0.2 1.3  NA 100
#3    4  NA 0.3  NA 0.4 100
#4    5  NA 1.4  NA  NA 150
#5    7 0.5 0.3 0.5 0.6 100
```

---

We could also use base R using `rowSums` finding out rows where there is at least one non-NA value.

```
cols <- 2:5 #Use this as index for columns for c1 to c10, here I have only till c4
df[rowSums(!is.na(df[cols])) > 0, ]


#  date  c1  c2  c3  c4   Q
#1    1 0.1  NA  NA  NA 300
#2    2  NA 0.2 1.3  NA 100
#4    4  NA 0.3  NA 0.4 100
#5    5  NA 1.4  NA  NA 150
#7    7 0.5 0.3 0.5 0.6 100
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = 1:7, c1 = c(0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.5
), c2 = c(NA, 0.2, NA, 0.3, 1.4, NA, 0.3), c3 = c(NA, 1.3, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.5), c4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.4, NA, NA, 0.6), Q = c(300L, 
100L, 200L, 100L, 150L, 200L, 100L)), .Names = c("date", "c1", 
"c2", "c3", "c4", "Q"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Might have some small speed gains with `filter(rowSums(is.na(.[2:5])) != 4L)`?

Comment: @snoram yes, that would work too although I am not sure if that would be faster.

Comment: some more hacky (and seemingly fast alternatives): `has_min <- function(x) !is.na(do.call(pmin, c(x, list(na.rm = TRUE)))); filter(df, has_min(.[2:5]))`

Answer (score 1):

To understand what happened you can try

```
df %>% mutate(rowSums(.[2:5]!="NULL"))
date  c1  c2  c3  c4   Q rowSums(.[2:5] != "NULL")
1    1 0.1  NA  NA  NA 300                        NA
2    2  NA 0.2 1.3  NA 100                        NA
3    3  NA  NA  NA  NA 200                        NA
4    4  NA 0.3  NA 0.4 100                        NA
5    5  NA 1.4  NA  NA 150                        NA
6    6  NA  NA  NA  NA 200                        NA
7    7 0.5 0.3 0.5 0.6 100                         4
```

This will get what you want

```
df %>% filter(rowSums(.[2:5]!="NULL", na.rm = TRUE)>=1)
date  c1  c2  c3  c4   Q
1    1 0.1  NA  NA  NA 300
2    2  NA 0.2 1.3  NA 100
3    4  NA 0.3  NA 0.4 100
4    5  NA 1.4  NA  NA 150
5    7 0.5 0.3 0.5 0.6 100
```

Comment: There is nothing related to "NULL" here. Your code works just by chance just because `NA` compared to anything is still `NA`. You would get the same results by running `df %>% filter(rowSums(.[2:5]!="A.Suliman", na.rm = TRUE)>=1)` too

Comment: @DavidArenburg good to know. Actually, I thought 'NULL' wouldn't work since `> NA=='NULL' [1] NA` and `> NA==NULL logical(0)` but it surprises me, Now I get it, thanks.